# textatistic Error: Word to be hyphenated may have at most 100 characters

Tags: python, readability

I am trying to use textatistic to get a readability score (flesch_score) However, I am getting the error said “Word to be hyphenated may have at most 100 characters”

Here is my code:

def flesch_score(article):
return(textatistic.flesch_score(article))
df["flesch_score"] = df['Message'].apply(lambda a: flesch_score(a))

Comment: Do you get different results with `return textatistic( article ) .flesch_score`

Comment: Hi Doyousketch2, I tried, but return textatistic(article).flesch_score rendered an error said "model is not callable".

Comment: Hmm, well that's how they show it on their quickstart guide. https://pypi.org/project/textatistic/ Maybe you have to specify their import that way `from textatistic import Textatistic` then use a capital on your T.

Comment: Hi Doyousketch2, I tried, same error.

Comment: I cleaned my dataset again and everything is working now. With that said, it is very important to clean the dataset as Erin mentioned in her blog: http://www.erinhengel.com/software/textatistic/